# Dim other datasets on Bar Plot hover - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a stacked bar plot made in Chart.js and I am interested in a hover interaction.

In particular, when hovering over a bar, I would like that particular bar to maintain its color, while everything else to fade to 0.5 opacity.

Doing the reverse is easy, I just use the `hoverBackgroundColor` attribute on the dataset, but that is not quite what I want.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

Comment: I'm also looking for this, except that when the bar is stacked only one block should remain full opacity.